# VBox Kernel driver not installed (rc=1908)

Tags: microsoft-windows, virtualbox, root

I am trying to install Win10 64-bit in VM using VBox. Here is error message when I try to start the VM for the first time, after allocating space and other settings:

> Kernel driver not installed (rc=1908)
>
> The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver (vboxdrv) is either not loaded or there is a permission problem with /dev/vboxdrv. Please reinstall the kernel module by executing

```
'/etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup'
```

> as root. If it is available in your distribution, you should install the DKMS package first. This package keeps track of Linux kernel changes and recompiles the vboxdrv kernel module if necessary.

So I executed the command and then it gave me a > rather than the usual me@me~$ , what does this mean? I should have been asked for root if it was needed to make this file change, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it gave me a > rather than the usual me@me~$

You have included the single quote. You get `>` for every `ENTER` until you enter other single quote.

Press `Ctrl + D` to see actual error message. (Simply you can terminate with `Ctrl + C`)

> what does this mean?

Off-topic in this site. But let me tell you in single line. It allows scripting in multiple lines in terminal. I use in `awk`.

---

To solve your issue:

Open terminal and run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install dkms
sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
```

*EDIT*:

The above two commands solved the issue for me. If not working, follow the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r` dkms
sudo apt-get install --reinstall virtualbox-dkms
```

Finally try,

```
sudo -i
/etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
exit
```

**Note**:

- Restart to the system is *may* required

Comment: That doesn't fix it, I still get the same error, even after updating (sudo apt-get update).

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: @ThomasShera , you better try with `sudo apt-get install linux-generic`  (This should cover when your installed kernel is absolute). other way `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade ; sudo linux-headers-\`uname -r\`` . it means you have to update your kernel.

Comment: The 2nd set of commands worked for me on elementary os and after a reboot.