# Trouble installing Virtualbox on Freya with kernel 4.4.0

Tags: software-installation, kernel, virtualbox

I am having some problems installing Virtualbox on my Elementary Freya. Due to some hardware, I needed to install Linux Kernel 4.4. However, I can't seem to install Virtualbox properly. (I was using rc3 previously, just updated to rc7)

```
$ uname -r
4.4.0-040400rc7-generic
```

I downloaded and tried both version from the [website](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads).

```
virtualbox-5.0_5.0.12-104815-Ubuntu-trusty_amd64.deb
virtualbox-5.0_5.0.12-104815-Ubuntu-wily_amd64.deb
```

Both of it fails.

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
Stopping VirtualBox kernel modules ...done.
Uninstalling old VirtualBox DKMS kernel modules ...done.
Trying to register the VirtualBox kernel modules using DKMSERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-4.4.0-040400rc7-generic is not supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.4.0-040400rc7-gen onsult /var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/5.0.12/build/make.log for more information....failed!
(Failed, trying without DKMS)
Recompiling VirtualBox kernel modules ...failed!
(Look at /var/log/vbox-install.log to find out what went wrong)
```

Any ideas how to fix this? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: try `sudo apt-get --reinstall install virtualbox-dkms` and let me know :). Also see [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/3872/vbox-kernel-driver-not-installed-rc-1908/3873#3873)

Comment: Is it ok to install a newer kernel for elementary OS?

Comment: @Ravan I'm getting an error at the end of the apt-get command: [Pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/HGtMBz7i)

Comment: @JulianLai I'm not sure. But I needed the new kernel to support my touchpad, or else it wouldn't work. I am guessing from now on i need to get sources for Ubuntu 15.10 instead?

Comment: have you tried `sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-\`uname -r\` dkms` ?

Comment: @Ravan running that command states that `dkms` and `build-essential` are both up-to-date, and `linux-headers-4.4.0` cannot be downloaded through apt-get. I downloaded the kernel update from here: http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.4-rc7-wily/

Comment: then try installing headers manually and let me know

Comment: @jellene did it work for you?

Comment: @Sneetsher No, updating to any of the 4.4 linux headers won't work. I haven't tried downgrading back to the original packaged linux headers for 14.04 LTS. Will reply here when I do.

Answer (score 1):

I needed gcc4.9-multilib to recompile my DKMS modules after the upgrade.You can grab it out of the toolbox beta repository from Ubuntu.

If that didn't work, post the log:

```
cat /var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/5.0.12/build/make.log
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the version number is out of range of supported kernels because have this format `4.4.0-040400rc7-generic` but it have to be something like `X.X.X-XXX`

You could use a kernel from ubuntu repositories. Do you really need to use the 4.4 version?

```
sudo apt install linux-generic-lts-wily
```

Comment: everything works like a charm with that format too.