# VirtualBox on elementaryos

Tags: kernel, drivers, virtualbox

after today's update of elementaryos I am unable to run virtualbox machines. The error says

> The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver (vboxdrv) is either not loaded or 
>   there is a permission problem with /dev/vboxdrv. Please reinstall the 
>   kernel module by executing
>
> '/sbin/vboxconfig'
>
> as root.
>
> where: suplibOsInit what: 3 VERR_VM_DRIVER_NOT_INSTALLED (-1908) - The 
>   support driver is not installed. On linux, open returned ENOENT.

any clue how to fix it? cheers

Comment: try `sudo apt-get --reinstall install virtualbox-dkms` and let me know :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBox Kernel driver not installed (rc=1908)](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/3872/vbox-kernel-driver-not-installed-rc-1908)

Comment: I disabled SECURE BOOT in BIOS and it runs okay ... dunno why as I am not that experienced in Linux systems. But cheers for the effort

Comment: Disable the Secure Boot is no problem for Elementary? Because on reinstalling I´m always aked if I disable UEFI Boot.
If I do this, is there a problem?